# How to delete specific child in DataTable row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am working with jQuery DataTables and am in a situation where I have a row with multiple children in it, and want to delete only a select few, which I know the index of. Is there any way I can do that throughout the whole table?

[This is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQhkG.png)  - The rows with the red arrows are the ones I want to delete

I have tried this:

```
$(".meeting-product-row").next().each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == undefined) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
})
```

but this only works in the first page of the table. I want to delete ALL children row that do not have a class throughout the whole table, even the pages that are not showing. Is there any way to do so?

I need help...

Comment: You can use `$(this).remove();`

Comment: Your data table server site binding or client site binding?

Comment: @jishansiddique Yes I tried using that too, but again it will only work on the first page of the table

Comment: @jishansiddique client side

Comment: You have child row like tr inside table row?

Comment: If you're using datatables with client-side paging, then changing the HTML will not do what you want - datatables will just draw them back in when you change page.  You need to update the *data* that datatables is using and then get datatables to re-render the table.  Never change the HTML directly when using datatables.

Comment: @LoselMatos please check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/o6L49dug/)

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes that is exactly what I want to do, delete all the blank child rows from the parent element, but I just can't seem to find how to delete a specific child. On the datatables documentation they only explain how to delete all children.

Comment: @jishansiddique You can see the same problem with that JSFiddle, It works on the first page of the table, but if you go to next page, you can see that the rows are still there

Comment: @LoselMatos we got the point.